How to Restore the Single "Open File" Icon in VS Code's Source Control Tab?
In the Source Control tab of VS Code, there used to be a single "Open File" icon for quickly accessing a file. However, now I have to click on the three dots menu (...) and then select "Open File" from the dropdown, which adds an extra step.
Is there a way to revert this behavior and bring back the single "Open File" icon? I found the previous setup more convenient.
Checkout this new UI. I wish to restore the old one instead


Right click on the "...", and select "Open File" from the list of options:

It should add the icon back:

